# OpenGL 2 Texture Internal Formats GL_RGB8I, GL_RGB32UI, etc

Tags: opengl, textures

I'm rewriting a large part of my texturing code.  I would like to be able to specify certain internal formats: GL_RGB8I, GL_RGB8UI, GL_RGB16I, GL_RGB16UI, GL_RGB32I, and GL_RGB32UI.  These tokens do not exist in OpenGL 2.

When specifying these internal formats as arguments to glTexImage2D, the texturing fails (the texture appears as white).  When checking for errors, I get [EDIT:] 1282 ("invalid operation").  I take this to mean that the OpenGL is still using OpenGL 2 for glTexImage2D, and so the call is failing.  Obviously, it will need to use a newer version to succeed.  Enums like GL_RGB, GL_RGBA, and (oddly) GL_RGB32F, GL_RGBA32F work as expected.

I configure to use GLEW or GLee for extensions.  I can use OpenGL 4 calls with no problem elsewhere (e.g., glPatchParameteri, glBindFramebuffer, etc.), and the enums in question certainly exist.  For completeness, glGetString(GL_VERSION) returns "4.2.0".  My question: can I force one of these extension libraries to use the OpenGL 4.2 version?  If so, how?

EDIT: The code is too complicated to post, but here is a simple, self-contained example using GLee that also demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <GLee5_4/GLee.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>
//For Windows
#pragma comment(lib,"GLee.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"glu32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"glut32.lib")

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const int screen_size[2] = {512,512};
#define TEXTURE_SIZE 64

//Choose a selection.  If you see black, then texturing is working.  If you see red, then the quad isn't drawing.  If you see white, texturing has failed.
#define TYPE 1

void error_check(void) {
    GLenum error_code = glGetError();
    const GLubyte* error_string = gluErrorString(error_code);
    (error_string==NULL) ? printf("%d = (unrecognized error--an extension error?)\n",error_code) : printf("%d = \"%s\"\n",error_code,error_string);
}

#if   TYPE==1 //############ 8-BIT TESTS ############
    inline GLenum get_type(int which) { return (which==1)?    GL_RGB8: GL_RGB; } //works
#elif TYPE==2
    inline GLenum get_type(int which) { return (which==1)?   GL_RGBA8:GL_RGBA; } //works
#elif TYPE==3
    inline GLenum get_type(int which) { return (which==1)?  GL_RGB8UI: GL_RGB; } //doesn't work (invalid op)
#elif TYPE==4
    inline GLenum get_type(int which) { return (which==1)?   GL_RGB8I: GL_RGB; } //doesn't work (invalid op)
#elif TYPE==5
    inline GLenum get_type(int which) { return (which==1)? GL_RGBA8UI:GL_RGBA; } //doesn't work (invalid op)
#elif TYPE==6
    inline GLenum get_type(int which) { return (which==1)?  GL_RGBA8I:GL_RGBA; } //doesn't work (invalid op)
#elif TYPE==7 //############ 16-BIT TESTS ############
    inline GLenum get_type(int which) { return (which==1)?   GL_RGB16: GL_RGB; } //works
#elif TYPE==8
    inline GLenum get_type(int which) { return (which==1)?  GL_RGBA16:GL_RGBA; } //works
#elif TYPE==9
    inline GLenum get_type(int which) { return (which==1)? GL_RGB16UI: GL_RGB; } //doesn't work (invalid op)
#elif TYPE==10
    inline GLenum get_type(int which) { return (which==1)?  GL_RGB16I: GL_RGB; } //doesn't work (invalid op)
#elif TYPE==11
    inline GLenum get_type(int which) { return (which==1)?GL_RGBA16UI:GL_RGBA; } //doesn't work (invalid op)
#elif TYPE==12
    inline GLenum get_type(int which) { return (which==1)? GL_RGBA16I:GL_RGBA; } //doesn't work (invalid op)
#elif TYPE==13 //############ 32-BIT TESTS ############
    inline GLenum get_type(int which) { return (which==1)?   GL_RGB32: GL_RGB; } //token doesn't exist
#elif TYPE==14
    inline GLenum get_type(int which) { return (which==1)?  GL_RGBA32:GL_RGBA; } //token doesn't exist
#elif TYPE==15
    inline GLenum get_type(int which) { return (which==1)? GL_RGB32UI: GL_RGB; } //doesn't work (invalid op)
#elif TYPE==16
    inline GLenum get_type(int which) { return (which==1)?  GL_RGB32I: GL_RGB; } //doesn't work (invalid op)
#elif TYPE==17
    inline GLenum get_type(int which) { return (which==1)?GL_RGBA32UI:GL_RGBA; } //doesn't work (invalid op)
#elif TYPE==18
    inline GLenum get_type(int which) { return (which==1)? GL_RGBA32I:GL_RGBA; } //doesn't work (invalid op)
#elif TYPE==19 //############ 32-BIT FLOAT ############
    inline GLenum get_type(int which) { return (which==1)?  GL_RGB32F: GL_RGB; } //works
#elif TYPE==20
    inline GLenum get_type(int which) { return (which==1)? GL_RGBA32F:GL_RGBA; } //works
#endif

GLuint texture;
void create_texture(void) {
    printf("    Status before texture setup: "); error_check();

    glGenTextures(1,&texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture);

    printf("    Status after texture created: "); error_check();

    GLenum data_type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE;
    int data_length = TEXTURE_SIZE*TEXTURE_SIZE*4; //maximum number of channels, so it will work for everything
    unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[data_length];
    for (int i=0;i<data_length;++i) {
        data[i] = (unsigned char)(0);
    };

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,get_type(1), TEXTURE_SIZE,TEXTURE_SIZE, 0,get_type(2),data_type,data);

    printf("    Status after glTexImage2D: "); error_check();

    delete [] data;

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    printf("    Status after texture filters defined: "); error_check();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    switch (key) {
        case 27: //esc
            exit(0);
            break;
    }
}

void draw(void) {
    glClearColor(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0); //in case the quad doesn't draw
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glViewport(0,0,screen_size[0],screen_size[1]);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0,screen_size[0],0,screen_size[1]);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex2f(0,0);
    glTexCoord2f(2,0); glVertex2f(screen_size[0],0);
    glTexCoord2f(2,2); glVertex2f(screen_size[0],screen_size[1]);
    glTexCoord2f(0,2); glVertex2f(0,screen_size[1]);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(screen_size[0],screen_size[1]);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutCreateWindow("Texture Types - Ian Mallett");

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    printf("Status after OpenGL setup: "); error_check();

    create_texture();

    printf("Status after texture setup: "); error_check();

    glutDisplayFunc(draw);
    glutIdleFunc(draw);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also make sure that all errors were processed before calling `glTexImage2D`, so that you're only seeing the errors that come from there.

Comment: Added an example that demonstrates the problem, with said error checking.  Thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> When checking for errors, I get [EDIT:] 1282 ("invalid operation"). I take this to mean that the OpenGL is still using OpenGL 2 for glTexImage2D, and so the call is failing.

[OpenGL errors](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GL_Error_Codes) are not that complex to understand. `GL_INVALID_ENUM/VALUE` are thrown when you pass something an enum or value that is unexpected, unsupported, or out-of-range. If you pass "17" as the internal format to `glTexImage2D`, you will get `GL_INVALID_ENUM`, because 17 is not a valid enum number for an internal format. If you pass 103,422 as the width to `glTexImage2D`, you will get `GL_INVALID_VALUE`, because 103,422 is almost certainly larger than `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_2D`'s size.

`GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is always used for *combinations* of state that go wrong. Either there is some context state previously set that doesn't mesh with the function you're calling, or two or more parameters combined are causing a problem. The latter is the case you have here.

If your implementation didn't support integer textures at all, then you would get `INVALID_ENUM` (because the internal format is not a valid format). Getting `INVALID_OPERATION` means that something else is wrong.

Namely, this:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,get_type(1), TEXTURE_SIZE,TEXTURE_SIZE, 0,get_type(2),data_type,data);
```

Your `get_type(2)` call returns `GL_RGB` or `GL_RGBA` in all cases. However, when using integral [image formats](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Color_formats), you ***must*** use a [pixel transfer format with `_INTEGER` at the end](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_format).

So your `get_type(2)` needs to be this:

```
inline GLenum get_type(int which) { return (which==1)? GL_RGB16UI: GL_RGB_INTEGER; }
```

And similarly for other integral image formats.

Comment: I was working from the first link, mostly, which didn't mention _INTEGER.  Changing the code above certainly works, but for integer textures, I see black (note, change "data[i] = (unsigned char)(0);" to 128 first).  Does this have anything to do with fixed function's interpretation of "integral formats will resolve to a vector of integers"--i.e., fixed function drawing + OpenGL 4 textures = undefined behavior?

Comment: @Ian: First, integer textures are GL 3, not GL 4. Second, integer textures don't work with fixed function; you have to use shaders with them.

Comment: I should clarify that I meant: fixed function drawing + integer textures != sense; naturally, floating point GL 3, 4 textures work fine.  Anyway, awesome, thanks!