# Problems creating an integral 1D texture in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, textures

Why is the following code generating `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`?

```
int8_t  bytes[256];
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  bytes[i] = (int8_t) i;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_R8I, 256, 0, GL_RED, GL_BYTE, bytes);
/* Here I get GL_INVALID_OPERATION */
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenGL 2 Texture Internal Formats GL\_RGB8I, GL\_RGB32UI, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278928/opengl-2-texture-internal-formats-gl-rgb8i-gl-rgb32ui-etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself! Apparently one must use the suffix `_INTEGER` on the format specifier  (`GL_RED_INTEGER`) when transferring pixels to a texture using integral format. More information here: [Pixel Transfer](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer)