# Color pick with uint 32bit texture

Tags: c++, opengl

/*because of marking as duplicate: This question is different to [OpenGL 2 Texture Internal Formats GL_RGB8I, GL_RGB32UI, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278928/opengl-2-texture-internal-formats-gl-rgb8i-gl-rgb32ui-etc) because I don't have the problem that the textures are white or black, everything is working exept the reading(picking) also, I'm using one channel textures instead of 3/4 channel textures */

I'm trying to read unsigned integers with the glReadPixels command.
the following code, which is using rgb byte values is working correctly,

**Texture and Framebuffer init**

```
glGenTextures(1, &nTargetTexture); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, nTargetTexture);
glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGB, nWidth, nHeight); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);      
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glGenFramebuffers(1, &nFramebufferID);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, nFramebufferID);
pglFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, nTargetTexture, 0);
const GLenum draw_buffers[] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
glDrawBuffers(1, draw_buffers);

GLenum eFramebufferOk = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER);
GLError();

switch (eFramebufferOk)
{
    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNDEFINED:
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(CREATE_FRAME_BUFFER_FAILED);
    }
    break;
    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT:
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(CREATE_FRAME_BUFFER_FAILED);
    }
    break;
    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT:
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(CREATE_FRAME_BUFFER_FAILED);
    }
    break;
    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DRAW_BUFFER:
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(CREATE_FRAME_BUFFER_FAILED);
    }
    break;
    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_READ_BUFFER:
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(CREATE_FRAME_BUFFER_FAILED);
    }
    break;
    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED:
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(CREATE_FRAME_BUFFER_FAILED);
    }
    break;
    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MULTISAMPLE:
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(CREATE_FRAME_BUFFER_FAILED);
    }
    break;
    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_LAYER_TARGETS:
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(CREATE_FRAME_BUFFER_FAILED);
    }
    break;
    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE:
    {           
    }
    break;
    default:
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(CREATE_FRAME_BUFFER_FAILED);
    }
    break;
}
```

**A simple test fragmentshader**

```
#version 430 core

layout(location = 0) out vec3 colorPickOutput;

void main (void)  
{   
    colorPickOutput= vec3(1,0.5f,0);
}
```

This fragmentshader is working: to test it, I printed it out to the GL_BACK buffer.

**Read from Framebuffer**

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, nFramebufferID);

GLubyte result[3]; 
glReadPixels(static_cast<int>(x), static_cast<int>(y),1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &result);
```

But this code is only usefull, if you have a maximum of 256^3 objects to pick.
I tryed to run this code with GL_R32UI textures to set the maximum of pickable items to 2^32 (4.294.967.296), but it still doesn't work, I replaced following lines:

**Replaced lines**

```
glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_R32UI, nWidth, nHeight); 

layout(location = 0) out ivec3 /*also tryed uint*/ colorPickOutput;

void main (void)  
{   
    colorPickOutput= ivec3(5,0,0); /*also tryed uint(5);*/
}

GLuint result[1];  //also tryed with result[3]
glReadPixels(static_cast<int>(x), static_cast<int>(y),1, 1, GL_RED/*also tryed with GL_RGB*/, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &result);
```

but it gives me "GL_INVALID_OPERATION" error if I use the "glGetError()" command.

Is it possible to read one uint pixel from a texture?
Am I maybe using the wrong command for reading uint pixels?

Comment: btw: I don't use qt or other libs... just pure openGL

Comment: You've used glGetError after every GL call to narrow down the error? Which particular statement causes the problem?

Comment: it appears after glReadPixels

Comment: `glReadPixels` performs a pixel transfer operation too.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: What do you mean? I'm still using glReadPixels

Comment: Yes. And `glReadPixels` performs a pixel transfer operation. That question explains how to perform pixel transfer operations with integer textures. My point is that the correction it talks about is just as true of `glReadPixels` as `glTexImage2D`.

Comment: I don't see this as a dublicate... It is another question and has nothing to do with OpenGL 2 Texture Internal Formats GL_RGB8I, GL_RGB32UI, etc ... BTW on this site: https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml from khronos group they say, that one channel textures don't work with glTexImage2D

Comment: can you please undo the duplicate stuff?

Comment: Or at least tell me why it is a duplicate?

Comment: It is a duplicate because the other answer explains exactly why you get an invalid operation when the texture was created with an integer format but you try to read from it with a non-integer format type. glReadPixels and glTexImage2D both do basically the same thing so the corresponding arguments have the same effect

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I try to read from it with an Integer format: glReadPixels(static_cast<int>(x), static_cast<int>(y),1, 1, GL_RED/*also tryed with GL_RGB*/, **GL_UNSIGNED_INT**, &result); what do I have to change?

Comment: I'm not going to tell you. Not because I enjoy making you suffer, but because OpenGL is a complicated API in places and you need to be able to figure out stuff for yourself. It *does* have something to do with GL_RGB8I etc. Re-read the other question and think about the combination of arguments (plural), not just individual.

Comment: ok, GL_INVALID_OPERATION means, that more then one thing is wrong. also https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_format here they say, that GL_FLOAT_32_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8_REV (maybe is the same than GL_R32UI) is a special format, which uses GL_DEPTH32F_STENCIL8. but what has the stencil/depthbuffer to do with the colorbuffer? I don't realy get it...

Comment: I think I have to read a little bit more about OpenGL to answer this question ;)

Comment: but one small questen... : is it posible to read a pixelvalue out of an 32bit integer value?

Comment: Yes it is possible. What you are trying to do is perfectly OK, you just need to read the other answer *carefully* and apply to your own code

Comment: @HughFisher if I could downvote your comments, I would. This tone is simply unacceptable.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I answered as I thought best, and nobody else was offering to help.

For the benefit of people who find this question and answer in future, why don't you write a better answer with an acceptable tone? Show me what I should have done.