# How to write integers to a texture buffer in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I am really confused with all of the type formats in OpenGL. I would essentially like to create a texture that I can write integers to, and also read integers from. I have tried the following:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32I, bufferRes.x, bufferRes.y, 0, GL_RED, GL_INT, NULL);
```

This gives me an "INVALID OPERATION" error. If I change `GL_R32I` to `GL_RED` I don't get this error. But isn't `GL_R32I` the correct format? If not, what is this for?

Also, if I wanted to read this texture in the shader as floats, I know that in another case where I used 16 bit integers I did:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R16_SNORM, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_SHORT, NULL)
```

And this was the correct way to do it. But there is no `GL_R32_SNORM`. I am really confused with all of these, because I remember `GL_R16I` working, but `GL_R32I` is not.

Comment: @Rabbid It does support it, turns out I had the wrong format for the 7th argument, should have been GL_RED_INTEGER instead of GL_RED. I've added an answer if it's of any help to anyone.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question was reopened, and since I found what the problem was, I may as well explain the error. The error is that in this line:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32I, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_INT, NULL);
```

`GL_RED` should be `GL_RED_INTEGER`. I found this solution in Nicol Bolas' answer in the link to the duplicate question when this one was closed.

[OpenGL 2 Texture Internal Formats GL_RGB8I, GL_RGB32UI, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278928/opengl-2-texture-internal-formats-gl-rgb8i-gl-rgb32ui-etc)

Though that question deals with `GL_RGB32UI` and not `GL_R32I` as in my case, the problem was essentially the same, the missing `_INTEGER` suffix for the 7th argument.

This is from the OpenGL wiki, also linked in the duplicate question:

> ... For integer pixel types, using a
>   floating-point format means that the pixels will be assumed to be
>   normalized integers. And thus they will be interpreted as normalized
>   values.
>
> If you want to transfer integral data to integral image formats, you
>   must suffix the pixel format with "_INTEGER". This states that the
>   client-side pixel data is integer rather than floating-point. You
>   should only use the "_INTEGER" format suffix with integral image
>   formats.

As to the question of why the format `GL_R32_SNORM` doesn't exist, while `GL_R16_SNORM` does, I was told that there would be no point in reading 32-bit integers as normalised single precision floats as the loss of precision would be pretty big. Thanks to Nicol and derhass for helping me out.